# Initializing 1 Vector and 1 Map in a class

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector, initialization

I have been trying to initialize 1 vector and 1 map in a class.
So to put it simply, once the class or rather a new object has been created, a vector and a map will then be generated or initialized to be able to store items.

How can i actually go about doing it? I am rather clueless and have not found any source on how will i be able to do this. Help is appreciated.

In Nodes.H

```
class nodes
{
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &, const nodes&);
vector<string> dataItemsVec;
map<int,int> fingertable;

private:
int nodeNum;    // node number
string dataItems; // data items
public:
nodes();    
nodes(int, string) : dataItemsVec(){} && fingertable(){}; // i am not sure how to do it
~nodes();
}
```

In Nodes.cpp

```
#include "nodes.h"

ostream &operator<<(ostream &printout, const nodes &node)
{
printout<< node.nodeNum << endl;
return printout;
}

nodes::nodes()
{
nodeNum = 0;
dataItems = "";
}

nodes::nodes(int nodeNum,string dataItems)
{
this->nodeNum=nodeNum;
this->dataItems=dataItems;
}
```

Upon initializing this new object called 'nodes'.
A vector will be initialized with 0 values to store dataItems.
A map will be initialized with 0 values to store other variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to do anything.  The default constructor for `vector` and `map` cause them to be correctly initialised.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the proper syntax :

in nodes.h

```
nodes();
nodes(int, string);
```

in nodes.cpp

```
    nodes():
    nodeNum(0),
    dataItem(""),
    dataItemsVec(),
    fingerTables()
    {
    }

    nodes::nodes(int i_nodeNum, string i_dataItem):
    nodeNum(i_nodeNum),
    dataItem(i_dataItem),
    dataItemsVec(),
    fingerTables()
    {
    }
```

Althgough, in your case, you don't need to do anything, since the default constructor of STL container does it for you.